# How to Define callback function for resize just left side in jQuery-UI

Tags: jquery-ui

I have a page with a jquery-ui resize object and I know how to provide a callback function when the object is resized, but it there a way to provide a callback function that only executes if the left side of the div is resized?

Here's what I have so far.  It calls function resizeGrid() when the div is resized from any direction.

```js
    $("div").resizable({
            resize: resizeGrid,
            handles: 'n, e, s, w'
          });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compare `ui.originalPosition.left` with `ui.position.left`, this will tell you if left size is being resized. Like this:

```js
$('div').resizable({

  handles: 'n, e, s, w',
  resize: function(e, ui) {
    var instance = $(this).resizable('instance');
    console.log(ui.position.left != ui.originalPosition.left)
  }
})
```

```css
 #resizable {
   width: 200px;
   height: 200px;
   border: solid 1px black;
 }
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css">

<div id="resizable"></div>
```